# Numpyarray data stored in .pkl format file. How to get image from this Numpyarray stored in .pkl format?

Tags: python, numpy, medical-imaging

> I have data stored in the NumPy array in .pkl file format. I
> only had an idea that data consists of low-dose CT DICOM images. But as the
> data is in array format I don't know what the original images look
> like. I am stuck at this point may be my question is also not valid
> but still, does anybody have knowledge about it. I don't know whether my question is valid but I
> I am confused here and I want to get images from it
>
> This is the .pkl format file lowDose_CT.pkl  and when I read this file
> I got the following output
>
> output
>
> [[array([[[-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
> [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
> [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
> ...,
> [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
> [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
> [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000]],
>
> ```
>    [[-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     ...,
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000]],
>
>    [[-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     ...,
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000]],
>
>    ...,
>
>    [[-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     ...,
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000]],
>
>    [[-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     ...,
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000]],
>
>    [[-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     ...,
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000]]], dtype=int16), array([[[-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     [-1000, -1000, -1000, ..., -1000, -1000, -1000],
>     ...,........
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe consider using a [program](https://www.slicer.org/) that can display this format. As far as I know, getting -1000 HU in some places is normal, as this represents the radiodensity of air.

Comment: But what about images that I want from it. Like you are saying I can implement preprocessing, adding thresholding, implementing cropping, on this NumPy array that is stored in .pkl format?

Comment: I mean you should maybe change the array to a format that is readable by the program I mentionned. I think each row in each array is a pixel, and each array in the total list is a row or a column. I would convert it to the standard from https://www.dicomstandard.org/current